# Could you simplify this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with this structure:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`sizes` (
  `id_size` INT NOT NULL ,
  `cm_min` INT NOT NULL ,
  `cm_max` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_size`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

This query returns the width and the height of the size 5:

```
select cm_min, cm_max from sizes where id_size = 5;
```

which are:

```
45, 56
```

Well, I want to get all the sizes that have the cm_min or cm_max between this range.
I tought something like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83e93/51

It works, but there is sizes that are not between any range.
I mean, if i have this:

```
id_size    cm_min    cm_max
1          56        59
2          63        67
3          70        74
4          76        79
5          83        86
6          60        62
7          12        14
```

If I've the values of the id_size 6, and I execute the previous query it'll returns 0 rows selected, and I want get the id_size of the sizes higher and smaller than this, although not strictly between the values. In this case would return:

```
id_size    cm_min    cm_max
1          56        59
2          63        67
```

Or for example if have the values of te id_size 7 which is the minor value, i need get the next minor value, in my case is:

```
id_size    cm_min    cm_max
1          56        59
```

Or if i've the higher values I'd need the id of the size wich has the second higher values.

Then if the first query that i posted doesn't has any result I do this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83e93/32/0

It works to. So, my question is:
**Can I do the same with only one query?**

I hope I was clear in my explanation and I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Below SQL would help you get started, which will return all the rows which are higher or lower than selected id e.g. here for id = 6

```
SELECT id_size 
FROM sizes 
WHERE (cm_min < 60 or  cm_min > 62) and
(cm_max < 60 or cm_max > 62);
```

**[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c08f3/4)**

**Update - Example**

Below I have provided more closer example to your need:
Remove `LIMIT 1` if you need all the records, lower and higher

```
SELECT id_size , 'lower'
FROM sizes 
WHERE (cm_min < 12 AND cm_max < 12)  
LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT id_size , 'HIGHER'
FROM sizes 
WHERE (cm_min > 14 AND cm_max > 14)
LIMIT 1
```

[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c08f3/10)

Comment: Yes, I've modify it and it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83e93/32/0. But read again my first post, I've edited it and maybe you know a better solution.

Comment: Really thanks Minesh, but it returns 1 and 2 ids. The values of the id_size 5 are 83 and 86. Are the higest, so then it'd return the id of the second highest value. I explain it in the first post.

Comment: @Joan You should lookout for stored procedure or function for this.

Comment: Ok Minesh, I'll do this. See this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890718/how-to-simplify-my-query#comment20884177_14890718