# What would be the fastest and/or simplest way to do this?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table and query:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sizes` (
  `id_size` INT NOT NULL ,
  `cm_min` INT NOT NULL ,
  `cm_max` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_size`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

insert into sizes values
(1,          56,        59),
(2,          63,        67),
(3,          70,        74),
(4,          76,        79),
(5,          83,        86),
(6,          60,        62),
(7,          12,        14);

  SELECT * FROM sizes
  WHERE cm_min >= 13 AND cm_min <= 66 OR
  cm_max >= 13 AND cm_max <= 66
  AND cm_min =
    (SELECT min(cm_max) FROM sizes
    WHERE (cm_min >= 13 AND cm_min <= 66) OR
    (cm_max >= 13 AND cm_max <= 66))
UNION
  SELECT * FROM sizes
  WHERE cm_min >= 13 AND cm_min <= 66 OR
  cm_max >= 13 AND cm_max <= 66
  AND cm_min =
    (SELECT min(cm_min) FROM sizes
    WHERE (cm_min >= 13 AND cm_min <= 66) OR
    (cm_max >= 13 AND cm_max <= 66))
ORDER BY cm_max ASC;
```

[See it in SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83e93/126/0)

---

Here is an example with the values 12 and 66 as can you see.
I need to add to this query the two next conditions:

1. If the range of the introduced values is the smallest of all the
   table, the query only returns the data of the row that has the
   smallest value. For example: If I have the values ​​9 and 10, the
   result will be the id_size 7 because it is the one with the smaller
   numbers.
2. If the range of the introduced values is the largest of all the
   table, the query only returns the data of the row that has the
   largest value. For example: If I have the values 112 and 113, the
   result will be the id_size 5 because it is the one with the larger
   numbers.

---

Would you know how to add the above conditions to my query?
Can I simplify it?

Comment: Your comparison seems to be faulty due to lack of parenthesis. I think you need something like `(...AND ...) OR ( ... AND ...)` instead of current format `... AND .. OR .. AND .. AND ...`

Comment: Thanks mate, I've modified it. Check the first post again i've modiffy some things, may be you can help me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. **Note** that the order is significant, @v1 must be the range minimum, @v2 the maximum.

```
SET @v1=112, @v2=113;

SELECT *
FROM   sizes
WHERE  (
       cm_min BETWEEN @v1 and @v2
       AND
       cm_max BETWEEN @v1 and @v2
       )
OR
       cm_min = (
         SELECT MIN(cm_min)
         FROM   sizes
         WHERE  (@v1+@v2) <= (cm_min + cm_max)
         )
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   sizes
WHERE  (
       cm_min BETWEEN @v1 and @v2
       OR
       cm_max BETWEEN @v1 and @v2
        )
OR
       cm_max = (
         SELECT MAX(cm_max)
         FROM   sizes
         WHERE  (@v1+@v2) >= (cm_min + cm_max)
         )
ORDER BY cm_max ASC;
;
```

Comment: Oh god! works great! really thanks. By the way, is it the faster way to do it?

Comment: No. The above query will not be optimized for search. How did you get the search value? U might need to consider to have a "size" entity relationship to normalize this search.

Comment: @Joan without knowing your table sizes and indexes, and running an `EXPLAIN SELECT...` it's hard to say if there is a faster way.

Comment: I'm going to edit your question to make it more comprehensive, then you can add more information about additional conditions to it afterwards.

Comment: Well, this is a change to the algorithm - you want v2 to carry greater weighting than v1. No time now - I'll have to give it some thought on Monday.

Comment: Ok @Raad, i hope so. I'm gonna try too. By the way, my tables will have 2000 rows, more or less. Thanks for all.